# Terminology: "flat geometry" in the context of clustering

Tags: clustering, terminology

[Sklearn's documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/clustering.html#clustering) refers to "flat" or "non-flat" geometry of clusters to describe the use-cases of their implemented clustering algorithms. Those terms are not directly defined. However, the following quote states:

> Non-flat geometry clustering is useful when the clusters have a specific shape, i.e. a non-flat manifold, and the standard euclidean distance is not the right metric.

So far, I do understand that a manifold type of shape is poorly represented by a cluster centroïd and that clustering such dataset should rather rely on local density, nearest neighbors, or connectivity constraint. However, I do not understand how it relates to the concept of flatness according to Wikipedia's definition:

> In geometry, a flat is a subset of a Euclidean space that is congruent to a Euclidean space of lower dimension.

It seems contradictory to me. For instance, a hypersphere is not geometrically flat but would be flat using sklearn's terminology.

My questions are then:

- Are flat and non-flat geometry a legit terminology in machine learning and statistics?
- If yes, what is the mathematical definition?
- If no, what is the most appropriate alternative? (e.g. manifold vs convex ???)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Are flat and non-flat geometry a legit terminology in machine learning
>   and statistics?

These are terminologies from Mathematics, they are valid in any field.

> What is the mathematical definition?

#### (Non) flat manifold

In mathematics, a (Riemannian) [manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold) is said to be [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_manifold) if its [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) is everywhere zero; otherwise non-flat. This is very different than the definition of [flat object in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(geometry)). According to that definition, only points, lines, and hyper-planes are flat (not for example hyperspheres or segments).

For example, set $\left\{(t,t):t\in(-1,1)\right\}$ is a 1D flat manifold in ${\Bbb R}^2$, set $\left\{(t,t^2):t\in(-1,1)\right\}$ is a 1D non-flat (positively curved) manifold in ${\Bbb R}^2$, and a hypersphere is an $n$D non-flat (positively curved) manifold in ${\Bbb R}^{n+1}$.

Accordingly, a cluster with a (non) flat shape corresponds to a (non) flat manifold.

Here are some examples from the document.

[image]

Points are concentrated around (A) two 1D non-flat manifolds (circles) which are non-convex, (B) two 1D non-flat manifolds (arcs) which are non-convex, (C) three 1D flat manifolds (segments) which are convex, (D) three 0D flat manifolds (centers as points) which are convex.

#### (Non) flat geometry vs a Flat

By "flat geometry" the document means "[Euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry)" not "[a flat object defined in geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_(geometry))". If we measure distances (consequently lengths, areas, volumes, etc.) via Euclidean distance we are obeying the Euclidean geometry, otherwise, we are obeying a non-Euclidean geometry. For example, if we measure a distance between two points by following a non-flat manifold ([a geodesic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)), we are obeying a non-Euclidean geometry. As an illustration,

[image]

In (A), the red line measures a distance obeying a flat geometry, the blue line measures the distance obeying a non-flat geometry (by moving along the non-flat manifold). If an appropriate map of manifold to a lower dimension is possible (B), obeying a flat geometry would be equivalent to obeying the non-flat geometry before mapping.